# How does open.spotify to detect mobile browser

Tags: browser

If you log in at https://open.spotify.com with your mobile you will be redirect to https://www.spotify.com and if you click on the button "launch web player" you will be redirect too. It's impossible to get the access of this page with a mobile. I tried to change my user agent but it doesn't work.

Do you know if it's possible to by pass this redirect ?

Comment: I don't seem to have the same issue. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SMW1.jpg) is what i see when i open the first link. Is that what you're trying to get?

Comment: Set your browser in desktop mode

Comment: I did, but I'm still not sure what page you're trying to get to.

Comment: You don't have enabled the desktop site. Because if you click on a music it will open the app

Comment: Try long pressing and opening in new tab or incagnito